# No sound from external midi

Tags: logic-pro

I'm new to Logic Pro X and I have a newb question.  I created an external MIDI track (#3) and made a recording from the attached keyboard, but I don't hear anything in Logic, why?  I have another track that's audio (#2) which I can hear.  Please see attached image.

[image]

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of the Library panel.  Not sure why "Off" is the name of the MIDI device.

[image]

Comment: I think an external MIDI track is meant to send MIDI messages to something outside your computer that can generate sound. Do you have an external synthesizer or keyboard hooked up? If you want Logic to generate sound from MIDI messages, that's a "virtual instrument" track, not an external MIDI track.

Comment: There is no virtual instrument track.  There is "software instrument", "external MIDI", "audio", "guitar or bass", and "drummer".  Using "software instrument" also produces no sound.  I also don't hear piano roll, maybe that's related?

Comment: Have you set the correct audio output?

Comment: Yes ...........

Answer (score 3):

When you create a new track, choose "software instrument", then in details is is suposed to be "an instrument Plug-in". Instrument should be " EXS24 (sampler)". Now it should work. I had the same problem as you, and I remember seeing a video about the basic facts you need to know about Logic Pro x and the guy in the video mentioned that this is how you are suposed to create your own track from a midi keyboard for example. I have no idea why it is this complicated, but now it works for me!

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky. I had this problem so thank you for your question :)

Based on the answers, I was able to 'hack' in.

Just a bit of clarification to update terminology; am using Logic Pro X.

Here is what I did:

> new (song) > external midi
> Then in the track details (below MIDI FX and above AUDIO FX), I chose my 'plug-in' software Kontakt 7.
> Kontakt 7's floating window appeared within LOGIC and viola! I now have audio and the correct instrument sounds also.

Thank you for the question and thanks to the answer folks!

[image: track information window]